# Probability of winning a contest after T minutes

Tags: probability

A contest has three participants. Participants draw numbers continuously at random; the probability of drawing the winning number is $p$.

Participant 1 draws numbers at a rate of 100 numbers per minute.
Participant 2 draws numbers at a rate of 300 numbers per minute.
Participant 3 draws numbers at a rate of 600 numbers per minute.

The first participant to draw the winning number wins. What is the probability that participant 3 will win this contest after $T$ minutes?

Note: "Win" means (1) that a participant draws the winning number, and (2) the others have not yet drawn the winning number.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: $=P(W=3|\tau>T)P(\tau>T)=\frac {600}{100+300+600}\exp(-(100+300+600)T)$.

Comment: @A.S. This does not seem intuitively correct. If there is only one player, is the probability really independent of $p$? $P \overset{?}{=} 1 \times \exp(-600T)?$ And why would $P$ decrease with time in this case?

Comment: I missed the extra factor of $p$ in the exponent.

Comment: So then $P = \exp(-600 \cdot pT)?$

Comment: But $\int_{T=0}^{T=\infty} P(T) \neq 0.6$ here. Please pardon any confusion.

Comment: Why did you drop a prefactor? It's $P(W=3, \tau>T)=\frac 3 5\exp(-1000pT)$

Comment: If "after T minutes" means $T+1>\tau\ge T$, just find the difference of the above expressions for $T$ and $T+1$. If you are asking about density - differentiate.

Comment: Since there is only one player playing at a rate of 600 time^-1, none is needed? And I still claim the integral over all times should come out to something reasonable. Since there is only one participant, S(P) should be 1, right?

Comment: With one player it will indeed be $P = \exp(-600 \cdot pT)$. The integral of this quantity is not 1, but expected time until the win.

Comment: That clarifies things a lot, thank you. I think I understand now.